# Where i can download Ubuntu 13.04 ISO torrents?

Tags: 13.04

i want to download ubuntu 13.04 desktop using torrent because speed is faster than normal download, where i can download iso torrent for ubuntu 13.04.
My torrent client is Utorrent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Direct links to all Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop ISO torrents:

- [Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop (64-bit)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)
- [Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop (32-bit)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)